# Laravel 7 - Why Toastr suddenly stopped displaying after I implement middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, plugins, routes, toastr

I was using a Toastr plugin that I got here [TJGazel Laravel Toastr](https://github.com/tjgazel/laravel-toastr) and it was working perfectly in all parts of my project where I implemented Toastrs (All of them are implemented inside all of my Controllers).

But at when I tried to put all of my web routes inside a middleware they stopped displaying though **it does not show any kind of error or message in console, developer's tool (Network tab) and laravel log files**. They only do not show/display.

My only hint for the cause of this problem is the middleware because I have a copy of my old project (right before I implemented the middleware) and ALL toastr in my old project works with no problems.

Here's my entire code for my routes **where my middleware is implemented** (web.php):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Spatie\Activitylog\Models\Activity;

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::view('unauthorized', 'unauthorized');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['user_middleware']], function() //Group middleware for authenticated / logged-in users
{
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Route::resource('master/vendor', 'Master\VendorController');
Route::get('vendor/datatable', 'Master\VendorController@datatable')->name('vendor/datatable');

Route::resource('master/product', 'Master\ProductController');
Route::get('product/datatable', 'Master\ProductController@datatable')->name('product/datatable');
Route::get('product/datatableTrash', 'Master\ProductController@datatableTrash')->name('product/datatableTrash');
Route::post('product/undoTrash/{id}', 'Master\ProductController@undoTrash')->name('product/undoTrash/{id}');
Route::get('master/product/history/{id}', 'Master\ProductController@history')->name('master/product/history/{id}');

Route::resource('transaction/purchase-order', 'Transaction\PurchaseController');
Route::get('transaction/purchase-order/vendor/popup_media', 'Transaction\PurchaseController@popup_media_vendor')->name('transaction/purchase-order/vendor/popup_media');
Route::get('transaction/purchase-order/product/popup_media/{id_count}', 'Transaction\PurchaseController@popup_media_product')->name('transaction/purchase-order/product/popup_media/{id_count}');
Route::get('browse-product/datatable', 'Master\ProductController@datatable_product')->name('browse-product/datatable');
Route::get('browse-vendor/datatable', 'Master\VendorController@datatable_vendor')->name('browse-vendor/datatable');
Route::get('purchase-order/datatable', 'Transaction\PurchaseController@datatable')->name('purchase-order/datatable');
Route::post('transaction/purchase-order/receive/{id}', 'Transaction\PurchaseController@received')->name('transaction/purchase-order/received/{id}');
Route::get('transaction/purchase-order/print/{id}', 'Transaction\SaleController@print')->name('transaction/purchase-order/print/{id}');

Route::resource('transaction/sales', 'Transaction\SaleController');
Route::get('transaction/sales/product/popup_media/{id_count}', 'Transaction\SaleController@popup_media_product')->name('transaction/sales/product/popup_media/{id_count}');
Route::get('sales/datatable', 'Transaction\SaleController@datatable')->name('sales/datatable');
Route::get('transaction/sales/print/{id}', 'Transaction\SaleController@print')->name('transaction/sales/print/{id}');

Route::get('transaction/stock', 'Transaction\StockController@index')->name('transaction/stock');
Route::get('transaction/stock/product/popup_media', 'Transaction\StockController@popup_media_product')->name('transaction/stock/product/popup_media');
Route::post('transaction/stock', 'Transaction\StockController@update')->name('transaction/stock');
Route::get('stock/report', 'Transaction\StockController@report')->name('stock/report');

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::get('/datatable_Activities', 'UserController@datatable_Activities')->name('datatable_Activities');
Route::get('/RecentActivities', 'UserController@RecentActivities')->name('RecentActivities');
Route::get('/password', 'UserController@Password');
//Route::get('/calendar', 'UserController@Calendar');
Route::post('user/updatePassword', 'UserController@updatePassword')->name('user.updatePassword');

});
```

Here's my code for `UserMiddleware.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class UserMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->user())
        {
            return redirect('unauthorized');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I tried to use `dd()` it shows the content returned by Toastr and found the values it supposed to return (I found No error or warning message). Again, the only problem is it does not display the toastr.

Here is my implementation of a Toastr in one of my Controllers:

```
Toastr::success('Product created Successfully', 'Success');
return redirect()->route('product.index');
```

And my layout file (`'layouts.backend.app'`) contains script and css files needed for a toastr (Where JQuery is loaded first, bootstrap then Toastr - both CSS and JS files). And I also included the `{!! toastr()->render() !!}` inside every blade file uses `@extends('layouts.backend.app')`.

> I've been searching related to this problem but found nothing yet.
> What might be the real cause of this and How do I fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

While debugging I found that when using a `return view()` it works but when it comes to `return redirect()->route('');` or `return redirect()->back();` it does not display.

**UPDATE (2/3/2021):**

It seems the problem is related to middlewares that I am using in routes (`web.php`), still no idea how to fix it without removing the middleware.

Comment: Could you add the code of your middleware to the question.

Comment: @Remul it is included already :)

Comment: The code  for `user_middleware` is not included. What does that middleware do?

Comment: It is not, add the code of your middleware class to the question please.

Comment: my bad.. I already added the source code now for the UserMiddleware. :)

Comment: Updated my post and added more information :)

Comment: Can you provide your `package.json` and `composer.json` so I can try to replicate this?

Answer (score 0):

As per reference from [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/toastr-notifications-not-working-after-other-package-is-installed) link, the issue might be because of the StartSession middleware. Try re-ordering the middlewares in kernel.php or there might be some other package that could be causing the issue because as per the above link , Spatie Google Tag Manager is causing an issue with session.Maybe a certain config of class is overridden in the container?

So if you could provide the composer.json we can may be able to find out the package that is causing the issue. The might be some other package that could be causing issue with the session.

Also try re-ordering the toastr service provider inside config/app.php to last position

if non of these works try using this : https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/